# How to count the items in array like the developer console

Tags: javascript, arrays

Script:

```
vL1 = ["AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "CS", "CS", "CS", "ND", "ND"];
vL2 = ["1",  "1",  "1",  "2",  "3",  "1",  "1",  "2",  "1",  "1"];

for(var i = 0; i < vL1.length; i++){
    thing = vL1[i] + " " + vL2[i];
    console.log(thing);
}
```

When I check the developer console, I see the following:

```
(3) AB 1
    AB 2
    AB 3
(2) CS 1
    CS 2
(2) ND 1
```

How can I modify the script so I can get the number of times `AB` with `1` appeared or `CS` with `1` appeared in my code to be used in other functions?

I just want to know the count for each `vL2` that is represented in `vL1`. It is important to associate `vL1` because that will let me identify the `vL2`, since it is not unique.

Comment: That is in the developer console and can't be used in other function. How can I get the same result in my code to put in an array or something so it can be used for other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the counts in an object. Also, utilizing [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can make it simpler to work with the indexes (e.g. you don't have to handle incrementing the index manually, etc.):

```js
    vL1 = ["AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "CS", "CS", "CS", "ND", "ND"];
vL2 = ["1",  "1",  "1",  "2",  "3",  "1",  "1",  "2",  "1",  "1"];

var counts = vL1.reduce(function(counts,vL1Element,index) {
  //initialize this index if it isn't set
  if(counts[vL1Element] == undefined) {
    counts[vL1Element] = {};
  }
  //set this count to 0 if it hasn't been set yet
  if (counts[vL1Element][vL2[index]] == undefined) {
    counts[vL1Element][vL2[index]] = 0;
  }
    counts[vL1Element][vL2[index]]++;
  return counts;
},{});
console.log(counts);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. How can I access, let's say the count for `AB` of `3`?

Comment: I hope this makes sense: > Object {Test%20It%20Out: Object, Here%20It%20Comes: Object...}

When I expand it I see the following:

> Test%20It%20Out: Object
> Here%20It%20Comes: Object

When I expand let's say `Here%20It%20Comes` I see the following:

2: 3
5: 15
10: 2
11: 29

How do I access let's say `Here%20It%20Comes` > `10` count, which should give me `2`.

Comment: perhaps reading [more about objects and accessing their properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) will give you more context...

Comment: I ended up using `count[property][property]` to get the count (e.g. `count['AB']['2']` gives me `1`). Thanks for the help! You paved the way.

Answer (score 2):

You might also do as follows;

```js
var vL1 = ["AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "CS", "CS", "CS", "ND", "ND"],
    vL2 = ["1",  "1",  "1",  "2",  "3",  "1",  "1",  "2",  "1",  "1"],
 result = vL1.reduce((p,c,i) => p[c] ? (p[c][vL2[i]] = p[c][vL2[i]] ? ++p[c][vL2[i]]
                                                                    : 1, p)
                                     : (p[c] = {[vL2[i]]: 1}, p), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I drill down?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Basically it's an implementation of [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) passed as a callback to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of a `for` iteration and a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) chain instead of `if` and `else`.

Comment: Thank you. So I was just curious as to how to access the count for AB > 3? I will check out the link to get better clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj={};
function log(a){
 if(obj[a]){
  obj[a]++;
 }else{
  obj[a]=0;
 }
 }
```

And then do:

```
log(thing);
```

Inside of your for loop, and than:

```
console.log(obj);
```

Obj now contains:
AB1:3;
....

Comment: Will it be for every entry? I can access it how? Thank you. What am I passing to `a`?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: A string, just like you do it with console.log

Comment: I get `undefined`.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: oh sorry im such an idiot... The variable of a function is deleted after the function execution ...

Comment: I can't upvote your comment unfortunately, calling yourself an idiot ;)